# changing the element type in Abaqus

Tags: abaqus

I am choosing shell element to model a composite plates using Abaqus. I found that Abaqus used S4R as an element type in the data file.
I want ABAQUS to use S4R5 instead of S4R. 
Could you please tell me how to do it 
thank you 
[defining element type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YKOS.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

Abaqus Analysis User's Manual 29.6.7 Three-dimensional conventional shell element library
S4R5 is a "4-node thin shell, reduced integration with hourglass control, using five degrees of freedom per node"
You should be able to change the element type in your input file from S4R to S4R5.

Just open the input file using text editor and change the S4R to S4R5 after keyword *element.

Comment: I have just started with Abaqus, so could you please detail where can i find the input file first.

Comment: This page should give you some ideas: 
http://bobcat.nus.edu.sg:2080/v6.14/books/gsa/default.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in CAE:

Select the "Mesh" Module

Select the "Assign Element Type" button (The one with "S4R")

This will open a dialogue box put these settings in to asign S4R5:-
Element Library - Standard,
Geometric Order - Linear,
Family - Shell

Changing Membrane strains from "finite" to "small" will give you the element you want.

- let me know how you get on